# how to dynamically sum multiple input records in a php while loop using jquery

Tags: jquery

my jquery code can dynamically sum only d 1st subject records out of 10 generated using a php-while loop. how can i dynamically get each subject total into their respective total input field

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';

//selecting all subjects from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sch`.subjects";
$subject_query = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$subject_query) die("Database Access Failed!" . $conn->error);

//looping through all the class subjects for recording
if($subject_query->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<table><tr><th>S/No.</th><th>Subjects</th><th class='me'>1st CA (30%)</th><th class='me'>2nd CA (30%)</th><th class='me'>Exam (40%)</th><th class='me'>Total (100%)</th><th class='me'>Grade</th><th class='me'>Remarks</th><th class='me'>Teacher</th></tr>";

$id = 0;
while ($subject_row = $subject_query->fetch_assoc())
{
//displaying the fetched data from dbase into a table
    $id++;
    echo "<tr><td>"."</td><td>". $subject_row['subName'] . "</td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca1'></td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca2'></td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca3'></td><td><input type='text' maxlength='3' id='ca4' readonly></td><td><select><option id='grd' value=''></option></select></td><td><select><option id='rmrk' value=''></option></select></td><td><input type='text' maxlength='3'></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Unable to fetch Records";
}
    echo "<input type='button' value='NEXT' onclick='history.go(+1); ' >";
    echo "<div id='btmbar'>";
    printf('Total Number of Records Fetched: %d', $conn->affected_rows);
    echo "<br><input id='btn2' type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'>";
    echo "</div></div></form>";

$subject_query->free();
$conn->close();
```

?>

The jquery code:

```
<body>
<script>
$(function() 
{
$("#ca1, #ca2, #ca3").on("keydown keyup", sum);
function sum()
{
    $("#ca4").val(Number($("#ca1").val()) + Number($("#ca2").val()) + Number($("#ca3").val()));
}
});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with you jQuery is that you are assigning the same id for multiple input which is why you are getting the current result.

One approach is to do it like so:

```js
$(".row .first, .row .second, .row .third").on("keydown keyup", function() {
  var siblings = jQuery(".row .fourth");
  var parent = jQuery(this).closest('.row');

  var first = parent.find('.first');
  var second = parent.find('.second');
  var third = parent.find('.third');
  var fourth = parent.find('.fourth');

  fourth.val(Number(first.val()) + Number(second.val()) + Number(third.val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>S/No.</th>
    <th>Subjects</th>
    <th class='me'>1st CA (30%)</th>
    <th class='me'>2nd CA (30%)</th>
    <th class='me'>Exam (40%)</th>
    <th class='me'>Total (100%)</th>
    <th class='me'>Grade</th>
    <th class='me'>Remarks</th>
    <th class='me'>Teacher</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class='row'>
    <td></td>
    <td>Subname</td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca1' class='first'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca2' class='second'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca3' class='third'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3' id='ca4' readonly class='fourth'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='grd' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='rmrk' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3'>
    </td>
  </tr>



  <tr class='row'>
    <td></td>
    <td>Subname</td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca1' class='first'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca2' class='second'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca3' class='third'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3' id='ca4' readonly class='fourth'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='grd' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='rmrk' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3'>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class='row'>
    <td></td>
    <td>Subname</td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca1' class='first'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca2' class='second'>
    </td>
    <td id='we'>
      <input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca3' class='third'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3' id='ca4' readonly class='fourth'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='grd' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option id='rmrk' value=''></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' maxlength='3'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This approach assigns a class to each input and search for siblings in the same row to perform operations.

Also, you change input type to number instead of text to show an error when the use enters a non-numerical value.

The code that you posted in your question will look like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';

//selecting all subjects from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sch`.subjects";
$subject_query = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$subject_query) die("Database Access Failed!" . $conn->error);

//looping through all the class subjects for recording
if($subject_query->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<table><tr><th>S/No.</th><th>Subjects</th><th class='me'>1st CA (30%)</th><th class='me'>2nd CA (30%)</th><th class='me'>Exam (40%)</th><th class='me'>Total (100%)</th><th class='me'>Grade</th><th class='me'>Remarks</th><th class='me'>Teacher</th></tr>";

$id = 0;
while ($subject_row = $subject_query->fetch_assoc())
{
//displaying the fetched data from dbase into a table
    $id++;
// We add required classes here .first, .second, .third and .fourth
// Also we add class to tr to access each tr separately from jQuery
    echo "<tr class='row'><td>"."</td><td>". $subject_row['subName'] . "</td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca1' class='first'></td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca2' class='second'></td><td id='we'><input type='text' maxlength='2' id='ca3' class='third'></td><td><input type='text' maxlength='3' id='ca4' readonly class='fourth'></td><td><select><option id='grd' value=''></option></select></td><td><select><option id='rmrk' value=''></option></select></td><td><input type='text' maxlength='3'></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Unable to fetch Records";
}
    echo "<input type='button' value='NEXT' onclick='history.go(+1); ' >";
    echo "<div id='btmbar'>";
    printf('Total Number of Records Fetched: %d', $conn->affected_rows);
    echo "<br><input id='btn2' type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'>";
    echo "</div></div></form>";

$subject_query->free();
$conn->close();
```

In a CSS id attribute should have unique value per page. Meaning that if you assigned ca1 value to an id for a certain element you can not assign again to any other element on the same page. Your code is populating the inputs with the same IDs over and over therefore jQuery can not distinguish which #ca1 to access since there are more than one. Therefore, only the first one is processed.

To combat this I added a class to each input (classes can assigned to multiple elements in each page) and also added a class to the parent TR element. Using this approach allow us to isolate each row and process it separately.

Hopefully, this will make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Kalimah, i have tried ur code but i can't possibly get it to work for me. from ur code do u mean i shouldn't echo out my table. bcos that is what am doing to loop through all the subjects and then echo them out without hard coding each subjects continuously. pls i still need more clarification if u don't mind. am new in this. thanks

Comment: hi Kalimah Apps. It has worked. am grateful. actually the fault is from me. am sorry for putting u through this stress. thanks

Comment: pls Kalimah Apps i want to ask u another question still from the same code above

Comment: from the code above, how can i use a switch statement if appropriate to automatically give a grade and remark. for example lets say the total score is 95 which is grade "A" then the remark should be "Excellent". Pls how can i go about it using php

Comment: Hi Kalimah Apps i just checked ur website but can't read a thing cos it's all Arabic. pls do u have good tutorials that i can download and also how can i read have ur website being displayed in English. Thanks

Comment: I think it is better to start a new thread for the other question as I can not reply in the comments and it is not relevant to the current question. My website does not have PHP tutorials but you can use Google translate or chrome to view it.